# Mailer function error

Tags: php, phpmailer

SMTP -> ERROR: DATA not accepted from server: 550 This message was classified as SPAM and may not be delivered

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "mail.cc.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "info@cc.com";
$mail->Password = "cc";
$mail->From = "cc.com"." <info@cc.com>"; 
$mail->AddReplyTo("cc1@gmail.com");
$mail->FromName = "info@cc.com";
$mail->AddAddress($climail);
$mail->AddCC("cc1@gmail.com");
$mail->Sender="info@cc.com";
$mail->IsHTML(true); 
$mail->WordWrap = 70;
$mail->Subject = $sub;
echo $meegate;
$mail->Body=$meegate;
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
$mail->Send();
```

Error occurring while sending mail.. mail not sent..

Comment: And the question is? I'd recommend you give [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good read

Comment: it's because all your mail ids that you used are not valid `gmail ids`. so they will send mail in spam folder.

Comment: added for example bro..

Answer (score 0):

You need to set SMTP host and also the port I guess which is 465:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "info@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "cc";
$mail->From = "gmail.com"." <info@gmail.com>"; 
$mail->AddReplyTo("cc1@gmail.com");
$mail->FromName = "info@gmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress($climail);
$mail->AddCC("cc1@gmail.com");
$mail->Sender="info@gmail.com";
$mail->IsHTML(true); 
$mail->WordWrap = 70;
$mail->Subject = $sub;
echo $meegate;
$mail->Body=$meegate;
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
$mail->Send();
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `Php mail function` ?

Comment: Tr using this :
`<?php
$to = "abc@example.com,";
$subject = "HTML email";
$message = "
<html>
<body>
<p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
";

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <a@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: b@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?> `