# Mailer function does not work for gmail

Tags: php, phpmailer

```
if($sql)
{
require("master/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "mail.php.net";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "krajesh@php.net";
$mail->Password = "password";
$mail->SetFrom("krajesh@php.net");
$mail->Subject = "subject";
$mail->Body = "<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' bgcolor='#006699' style='border:solid 10px #006699; width:550px;'>
<tr bgcolor='#006699' height='25'>
<td><img src='logo.jpg' border='0' width='200' height='60' /></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF'><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF' height='30'>
<td valign='top' style='font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; line-height:18px; text-decoration:none; color:#000000; padding-left:20px;'><b> Login details from $website_name </b></td></tr>
<tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF' height='35'>
<td style='padding-left:20px; font-family:Arial; font-size:11px; line-height:18px; text-decoration:none; color:#000000;'>Username :  $email </td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF' height='35'>
<td style='padding-left:20px; font-family:Arial; font-size:11px; line-height:18px; text-decoration:none; color:#000000;'>Password :$password</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF' height='35'>
<td style='padding-left:20px; font-family:Arial; font-size:11px; line-height:18px; text-decoration:none; color:#000000;'><a href='$website_url/index.php?activate=".$actvateid."' style='font-family:Arial; font-size:11px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none; color:#2200CC;'>Click Here</a> to activate your account</td>
</tr>
</table>";
$mail->AddAddress($email);
if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
echo "<script> window.location='index.php?sendsus'; </script>"; 
exit;
}
}
```

Did I make a mistake in the code or do I have to change the mailer function itself?
The mail function is working locally, but not working for gmail.. I also tried live but gmail is not working..

Comment: "Not working" is in no way a sufficient problem description.

Comment: *"mailer function not working for gmail"* - `$mail->Host = "mail.php.net";` ? you have an account there too? `krajesh@php.net` wow. You'd think you could fix your own mailing issue.

Comment: Plus, this is a repost of http://stackoverflow.com/q/30664520/

Comment: no i just put that for example but i have account in personal site.. with name krajesh@xyzexample.com

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong host and port number use this code

```
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 587;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80467/discussion-on-answer-by-faiz-rasool-mailer-function-does-not-work-for-gmail).